# getElementById and onLoad

Tags: javascript, onload, getelementbyid

HTML file ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/myJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myJS.myFunction();">
<p id="p01"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

External Javascript file (called myJS.js for convenience) ...

```
myJS = {
    myFunction: function()
    {
        //This works
        document.write("Hello world. ");

        //This does not work
        document.getElementById("p01").appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello world, again"));
    }
};
```

My best guess is that the node `p01` has not been created when `myJS` is executed, but I thought that `onload` would do the right thing with it.

Comment: Are you running `document.getElementById()` after `document.write()`?

Comment: `body.onload` is triggered as soon as the page **code** (that exact html/php/asp file) is rendered, not when all the elements have been loaded. `window.onload`, on the other hand, is triggered when all the elements have been loaded such as scripts, images etc.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? You should be able to render p01. Are you not getting it ?

Comment: @inhan I don't think so, `body onload=...` and `window.onload` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your external js really contains both lines of code you posted, the problem is that `document.write` is overwriting the whole HTML (it behaves like that as soon as the DOM is loaded). Then `getElementById` won't find any `#p01`, because it won't exist anymore.

If you simply remove the `document.write` call, your code is supposed to work (see a [live example](http://jsbin.com/ohuqeq/1/edit)).

Comment: Sorted, thanks. Now I know something about document.write that I didn't know before.

Answer (score 2):

Because `p01` is not yet added to the DOM.

Try like this:

```
<body>
<p id="p01"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = myJS.myFunction;
</script>
</body>
```